# T-SQL - Remove All Duplicates Except Most Recent (SQL Server 2005)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have a T-SQL function that will pull all records inserted into a main table within the last 60 minutes and insert them into a table variable. I've then got some more code that will filter that set into another table variable to be returned.

In this set I'm expecting some records to have multiple occurrences but they will have a unique date time. **I would like to delete every record that has greater than or equal to 3 occurrences, but keep the one with the most recent datetime value.**

EDIT: Sorry, I thought I was more clear than it appears I actually was.

This data is error log data from a legacy system, so duplicates can be expected. The idea is that if they cross a certain threshold they need to be reported.

For example, the below is what should end up in `@table_variable_2`:

```
   |   ColA  |  ColB |      DateTimeColumn      | ColC |
   ---------------------------------------------------
1  |    A    |   B   |  2015-08-24 11:06:14.000 |  C   |
2  |    A    |   B   |  2015-08-24 11:18:58.000 |  C   |
3  |    A    |   B   |  2015-08-24 12:07:45.000 |  C   |
4  |    A2   |   B2  |  2015-08-24 12:17:24.000 |  C2  |
5  |    A2   |   B2  |  2015-08-24 13:25:32.000 |  C2  |
6  |    A3   |   B3  |  2015-08-24 14:52:10.000 |  C3  |
7  |    A3   |   B3  |  2015-08-24 14:52:34.000 |  C3  |
8  |    A3   |   B3  |  2015-08-24 14:52:45.000 |  C3  |
9  |    A3   |   B3  |  2015-08-24 14:53:15.000 |  C3  |
10 |    A3   |   B3  |  2015-08-24 14:53:32.000 |  C3  |
```

This is what I expect to be returned:

```
   |   ColA  |  ColB |      DateTimeColumn      | ColC |
   ---------------------------------------------------
1  |    A    |   B   |  2015-08-24 12:07:45.000 |  C   |
2  |    A2   |   B2  |  2015-08-24 12:09:35.000 |  C2  |
3  |    A2   |   B2  |  2015-08-24 13:25:32.000 |  C2  |
4  |    A3   |   A3  |  2015-08-24 14:53:32.000 |  C3  |
```

It's okay to have some duplicates, there's just the chance of having a lot of them.

EDIT 2: Solved without the CTE function

```
DELETE @rtrn_tbl FROM @rtrn_tbl 
    AS a
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT ColA, ColB, MAX(DateTimeColumn) AS MaxDate, ColC FROM @rtrn_tbl
          GROUP BY ColA, ColB, ColC
          HAVING COUNT(*) > 2
   ) AS b
   ON a.ColA = b.ColA AND a.ColB=a.ColB and a.ColC = b.ColC
   WHERE a.DateTimeColumn <> b.MaxDate;
```

Comment: Sample data and expected output will be helpful. `r_count >= 3` is not going  to delete all the duplicates. In fact this query will still result duplicates

Comment: What do you mean by delete every record but keep one??? Are you saying that you want to delete all rows except the most recent one for rows that have more than 3 occurrences? It isn't very clear what you are trying to do here.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to use `PARTITION BY ColA, ColB, ColC ORDER BY DateTimeColumn DESC` instead, then you can delete all but one (the most recent):

```
WITH cte AS 
(
      SELECT ColA, ColB, DateTimeColumn, ColC, 
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ColA, ColB, ColC ORDER BY DateTimeColumn DESC) AS r_count
      FROM @table_variable_2
)
DELETE
FROM      cte
WHERE     r_count > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH cte AS (SELECT ColA, ColB, DateTimeColumn, ColC, 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ColA, ColB, DateTimeColumn,ColC
ORDER BY ColA, DateTimeColumn desc) AS r_count
FROM @table_variable_2)
, cte1 as (select * from cte where r_count >= 3)
DELETE FROM cte1
WHERE r_count <> 1
```

You can do one more `cte` to select all records with `r_count>=3`.And then delete to preserve the latest record.